# CreateUserWizard fires CreatedUser event at Step1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership, createuserwizard

I can't seem assign the CreatedUser event to the Finish step. Here is the ASP pretty much out of the box with 2 steps:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
    oncreateduser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" />
        <asp:WizardStep runat="server">
            ...Step 2 Controls...
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

I have custom controls on the second step that I want to use in the CreatedUser method, but I can't because it fires on Step 1.

edit: Customizing the step doesn't give me access to the "Create User" button's events, and it seems the CreateUserWizard wants all steps to fire the CreatedUser method. Can I at least separate the events so I can access methods separately from step 1 and step 2?

Answer (score 0):

`OnFinishButtonClick` event works for what I'm trying to do.